# Three Point Vortices Fluid Dynamics

Tags: applications, fluid-dynamics

I have been assigned a problem with two point vortices:

> Find two point vortices whose locations in the 2D plane and strengths $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ are such that their positions remain fixed in time.

**My actual Question is how to do this problem with 3 point vortices of strengths $\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3$ whose positions remain fixed in time.**

My proof for 2 vortices. *(DISCLAIMER I AM NOT SURE IF THIS IS CORRECT.)*

> Denote the complex potential of the two point vortices as $z_1,z_2$. 
>   The velocity induced on $z_2$ by the vortex at $z_1$ is,
>   $$w(z_1)=u-iv=\frac{\gamma_1}{2\pi i(z_1-z_2)}. $$
>
> The velocity induced on $z_2$ by the vortex at $z_1$ is,
>   $$w(z_2)=u-iv=\frac{\gamma_2}{2\pi i(z_2-z_1)}. $$
>
> Since inviscid vorticity is simply advected by the flow, the velocity is also with which the vortex moves:
>
> $$\frac{dz_1^*}{dt}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\frac{\gamma_1}{(z_1-z_2)}$$
>
> $$\frac{dz_2^*}{dt}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\frac{\gamma_2}{(z_2-z_1)}$$
>
> Where the * denotes complex conjugations.
>
> Adding and subtracting these two equations from each other, and got
>
> $$\frac{d}{dt}(z_1+z_2)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\frac{\gamma_1-\gamma_2}{z_1-z_2} \implies |z_1^*-z_2^*|=\text{ constant} =2R $$
>
> and
>
> $$\frac{d}{dt}(z_1^*-z_2^*)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\frac{\gamma_1-\gamma_2}{(z_1-z_2)} \implies |z_1-z_2|=\text{ constant} =2R$$
>
> This first result shows that the center of the two vortices is staying put while the second proves that the distance does not change. Writing then
>
> $$z_1=R\exp(i\theta), \text{ and} z_2=-z_1$$
>
> any of the two above equations of motion gives
>
> $$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{\gamma}{2\pi R^2} $$
>
> The first result shows that the centroid of the two vortices $\color{red}{\text{ is fixed within a distance } (??)}$, while the second proves
>   that their distance does not change. Thats the best description I've got.

**Any and all help/tips proofs would be very much appreciated. Thank you! **

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your proof of the 2 vortex is wrong, since you have not shown that the velocities are zero.

To solve the 3 vortex case lets assume that they are originally at $z_1,z_2,z_3$ and I will use a slightly different notation than you and call $w(z_j)$ the velocity of the vortex that is at $z_j$ 
$$0=w(z_1) = {\gamma_2 \over (z_1 -z_2)} +{\gamma_3 \over (z_1 -z_3)}$$
$$0=w(z_2) = {\gamma_1 \over (z_2 -z_1)} +{\gamma_3 \over (z_2 -z_3)}$$
$$0=w(z_3) = {\gamma_2 \over (z_3 -z_2)} +{\gamma_1 \over (z_3 -z_1)}$$
I am ignoring the $2 i \pi $ factors since the won't enter in the calculation
lets call $a_{ij} = {1 \over z_i -z_j}$ and write
$$ \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
 0& a_{12}& a_{13}
\\-a_{12}& 0& a_{23}
\\=a_{13}&-a_{23}&0
 \end{array}\right]\left[ \begin{array}{c}\gamma_1\\\gamma_2\\\gamma_3\end{array}\right]=\left[ \begin{array}{c}0\\0\\0\end{array}\right]$$
before I continue, notice that for the two vortice case the equations are

$$ \left[\begin{array}{cc}
 0& a_{12}
\\-a_{12}& 0
 \end{array}\right]\left[ \begin{array}{c}\gamma_1\\\gamma_2\end{array}\right]=\left[ \begin{array}{c}0\\0\end{array}\right]$$ which can only be solved with zero vortex intensities.

in order to solve we can consider an easy case, when all vortices are on the $x$ axis so that $a$'s are real. Then we have a cross product $[-a_{23},a_{13},-a_{12}]\times[\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3]=[0,0,0]$ so that by setting the $\vec{\gamma}$ vector to be parallel to $[-a_{23},a_{13},-a_{12}]$ we are done:
$$[\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3]=K[-a_{23},a_{13},-a_{12}]$$ for any real K.
Example: 
$$z_1,z_2,z_3=1,2,3$$,
$$a_{23}={1\over (2-3)} =-1 ; a_{13}={1\over (1-3)} =-1/2; a_{12}={1\over (1-2)} =-1 $$
$$[\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3]=K[1,-1/2,1]$$
Any 3 co-linear vortices should work (you remove the phase by adjusting the $K$), but I am not sure you can  find a non co-linear solution with 3 vortices.